# implement Google OAuth 2

Tags: iphone, oauth, google-api

I'm trying to implement Google OAuth 2 to get access to the Google APIs. 
When i try to exchange the code by an access token, it doesn't work.

I use this method to do it.

```
 (void)getAccessTokenwWithCode:(NSString*)code
{
      NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[@"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token" ]];
      [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
      NSDictionary *postBodyDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
                             code, @"code", 
                             @"my_client_id", @"client_id",
                             @"my_client_secret", @"client_secret", 
                             @"http://localhost", @"redirect_uri", 
                             @"authorization_code", @"grant_type", 
                             nil];

     NSString *postBody = [postBodyDic JSONString];
     NSData *data = [postBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
     [request setHTTPBody:data];
     [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];  

     AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request                             
     success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSURLResponse *response, id JSON) 
     {
         NSLog(@"%@", JSON);
     } 
     failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) 
     {
        NSLog(@"ERROR \n%@", error );
     }
     ];

     [queue addOperation:operation];
}
```

I get a 400 error

Anyone can help me to localize the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post the complete error message?

Comment: And which Google APIs are you going to be using (Mail, Calendar, Analytics, etc.)

Comment: @Claudio Cherubino this the complete eroor message            Error Domain=com.alamofire.networking.error Code=-1011 "Expected status code <NSIndexSet: 0x1109a0c0>[number of indexes: 100 (in 1 ranges), indexes: (200-299)], got 400" UserInfo=0x1109f850 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token, NSLocalizedDescription=Expected status code <NSIndexSet: 0x1109a0c0>[number of indexes: 100 (in 1 ranges), indexes: (200-299)], got 400}

Comment: @Mark S I want to use contacts api

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the AFNetworking classes, try using the [AFNetworking Extension for OAuth 2 Authentication](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFOAuth2Client). I haven't used it, but it looks like what you need.